# VBA : re-sort/re-order rows based on column values through specific range

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm fairly new to VBA, and have found this to be a great resource.  I understand enough to generally find someone else's code and modify it to what I need it to do, but I've been stumped here.  I've tried coding this several times in different ways, but can't seem to get it to work, and am not overly convinced I'm approaching it the right way to start with.  I'm hoping someone is willing to help me.

Here's a theoretical example of what I'm trying to do.

I have a sheet that contains groups of orders of a certain product type with their quantities listed by the step of the process they're currently at:

**Current orders in process**

[image: Current orders in process]

I need to "sort" them or re-order them so that:
   1. The orders are copied into a tab based on process step, with the furthest process step being listed first working back to the closest, and...
   2. Orders listed in the "complete" step need to be excluded completely, and...
   3. I need to do this for multiple product types, which have different numbers of process steps, so the end column needs to be identified somehow (as a dynamic variable, or some trigger)

For the example, it would look like this:

**Sorted data**

[image: Sorted data]

I've thought through a half-dozen ways to logically go about this and tried to figure out how to then do that with code, but I'm stuck ... and I have the feeling that there is probably 1 or 2 "best" ways to go about this that someone in this community probably knows off the top of their head.  Thank you in advance.

Edit: Here's my first attempt at coding the outline.  I realize there are some components missing, but would love feedback on whether this seems to be a usable, or efficient approach.

```
Sub test1()
Dim skuStartRow As Long, skuEndRow As Long
Dim qty As Integer
Dim colCheck as long, lastCol as Long


skuStartRow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=sku, after:=.Range("A1")).Row
skuEndRow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=sku, after:=.Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
' Code here to identify last column (lastCol) either by .UsedRange or by header?

For colCheck = 3 To lastCol

    For rowCheck = skuStartRow To skuEndRow

      qty = Cells(rowCheck, colCheck).Value
      If qty <> "" Then
        'copy current row and paste into destination worksheet
        MsgBox qty 'test to see if correct qty is displayed
      End If
    Next rowCheck

Next colCheck

End Sub
```

---

Update:

Still having problems.

1. I've copied/pasted the whole range of orders based on product type to a new sheet where it will be sorted.
2. I've inserted a column and used the match/index formula provided by Variatus (autofill down) to create an index column.
3. Insert new column and use RANK function to create a rank ordered list, as there are duplicates in the Helper/Index column.
4. Used INDEX/MATCH functions to return values into rank ordered lists for both work order number and quantity value.

The code I currently have works - except that it's hard-coded using FormulaRICI = ... commands.  I'm having major challenges figuring out how to convert the code to allow use of MATCH/INDEX functions with variables.  I need to do this b/c depending on product type there are varying amounts of total orders, as well as varying amounts of number of steps; so I need to have a dynamic range for both rows/columns.

I've looked at a bunch of examples but can't seem to find something that works correctly.  The most promising I've seen appears to be using the "replace" function in VBA, but my head's about to explode.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: your sorted data picture doesn't exclude orders listed in complete and also doesn't appear to be separated into different tabs based on process step. Will the it always be steps between Step1 and Complete? And do you need a new worksheet for each step, step1 to step2?

Comment: I'm confused: in your example output, shouldn't rows 3 and 9 be excluded since they are in the complete row?

Comment: Yes, you are both correct that my second picture is inconsistent with my description.  I was in a hurry when I posted the original...will edit.

QHarr - I don't need a new worksheet for each step; I merely need to import (or copy/paste) the rows into a different worksheet where other information already resides, but I need them to be in sequential order from last step to first step, top to bottom.

Comment: Copy/pasting to/from the worksheet is a very time-consuming process.  One approach would be to sort first on the worksheet; then copy the groups to the different sheets. You can easily sort the worksheet by using a helper column that returns the appropriate Step depending on which column contains Quantity. This can be done with a simple `LOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` function. For the rest of it, **before** you write any code, you must be clear and unambiguous as to what you want for a result. Then you can copy/paste the groups in code. There are more complex approaches but try this for a start.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I swear I didn't see your post until after I had completed my answer. In deference I awarded a thumbs-up to your reply.

Comment: @Variatus No problem. This happens from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you really need VBA for this. Please consider these steps.

1. Insert a column in your worksheet with this formula in row 2, copied down.
   `=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($D2:$I2<>0,0),0),0)`. The range D2:I2 is defined by D2 = Step 1 and I2 = "Complete". The formula finds the first non-blank cell in the range. The column could be hidden.
2. Sort the sheet on the helper column, largest to smallest.
3. Apply a filter.
4. Filter on the product.

What you see at this point is the list you wish to create using VBA, however including the 'Complete' column and any other columns to the right of it.

There are a number of ways of automating this process. You might write code to either insert the formula in the helper column automatically or its result. This could be done when needed, without having a permanent extra column. You could write code to do the sorting and filtering automatically, for example, based on a currently selected product. And, finally, you might write code to copy the result to another sheet, remove the unwanted columns there, and restore the original sheet to its original condition (presumably sorted by order number).

Comment: @ Ron & Variatus - Thank you both, I took elements from both of your similar responses to re-think how I was approaching this problem.  I've made a lot of progress in that I made it work just in Excel, and then converting to VBA code to achieve the same result.

However, I'm stuck again.  Update to original post to show what I've done so far and some more information to frame the problem.

Comment: Post the line of code that you are having a problem with.

Comment: @ Variatus - I figured it out!  Still being fairly ignorant of a lot of VBA things, it took me some trial and error of looking for other examples out there to decipher what I needed to do.  I was struggling to get the formatting correct for FormulaR1C1 using variables, but it's working now.  Thanks for your suggestion to use index/match as well as an initial formula to get me started!

Comment: Your question found an answer, and this answer should be marked for other visitors' benefit. If my answer served your purpose it is the one that should be so marked, but from what you write an outcome at least equally fair would be for you to post your own answer with your final code and select that.

Comment: @ Variatus Thanks for prompting me to mark your answer as correct - this is my first time posting.  I may go back and post the final code that I used, but I needed to do a handful of follow-on steps that I figured out on my own, but would have never gotten there without your post.  Ron Rosenfield also was helpful, but I think it would have been a stretch for me to use his suggestion to arrive at a composite solution using Index/Match without you providing the example formula, so I'm marking yours.  Thanks so much for your help.